# Django : changing browser zoom in production

Tags: django, django-templates, zooming

The zoom level of my website is not the same in production as it is in development. I would like the zoom level to be the same as it is in development. That corresponds to a 75% zoom in production. Is there a way to do this with Django ? Maybe in the settings or in the templates ?

Thanks in advance !

Comment: do you have `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
` in the head section of your HTML?

Comment: I have ```<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">```

Comment: I remove the ```shrink-to-fit=no``` and that solves the problem, thanks for the help !

Answer (score 0):

I know the question is already answered, there is one more way.

On the html page below the `<body>` tag, paste the below script

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    var browserZoomLevel = Math.round(window.devicePixelRatio * 100);
    // if zoom level is greater than 75
    if (browserZoomLevel>75){
        // find how much
        zoom_level = 100-(browserZoomLevel-75)
        // add percentage symbol with value
        zoom_percent = zoom_level+"%"
        // adjust the browser zoom level
        document.body.style.zoom = zoom_percent
      }

</script>
```

If the browser zoom level is greater than 75 percent, the above code will auto adjust to 75%.

Hope this helps someone. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Run your project in any other browser I faced the issue that my NavBar and Product-List page was extra zoom and then I tried to open my local project in other browser so there the same project without any changes running well.